# What is the key combination in 2.8 that brings up the cursor moving pie menu?

Tags: interface, shortcut

I saw it in some tutorial but I don't remember what it is called or where I found it and I can't find it again.

It was a pie menu that opens with a combination of hotkeys that has a bunch of options like "cursor to selection", "move to cursor" or similar. There might have been origin stuff in there too.

What is the key combination in 2.8 that brings up that cursor moving pie menu?

Answer (score 5):

It's called the "Snap" menu, opened with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the "industry compatible" shortcuts it's Shift + X